# android SQLite vs Flat Files

Tags: database, android, sqlite, flat-file

im creating a game right now and im a bit stuck on how to implement storage of levels. i need to be able to download level files from the internet ota. im not so familiar with transferring files ota, but i have some experience with databases (`mysql`). what would be a better way of storing the game's level data?

Comment: What is **ota**? (Quotes: "internet **ota**" and "transferring files **ota**")

Comment: Over The Air, I'm assuming.  You could store the data in a remote Mysql server if it's fine that they can't play the game without connectivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using sqlite will definetely decrease the time you spend coding, thus you can focus your effort in what is more important: the logic of the game. What you are going to store is simple data, then it won't worth the effort to use another method to save that info.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of reasons to use a DB.

If you have data that is **only read from and never change** (except total overwrite), please think of using **flat files**. A database may be an overkill in this scenario.

BTW, please consider putting the files in the external storage - it can help the user maintain low app memory - especially if the data files are big.